# Custom hamcrest matcher that works with "not"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I have some class (say, `Entity`).

I want to be able to

1. test that an instance of that is "valid", using some custom code to decide that
2. also test that an instance is not valid, ideally using the same code.

Using maven, surefire, JUnit 4.11 (and the hamcrest stuff shipped with it).

So I write a class something like this

```
class IsValidEntity extends TypeSafeMatcher<Entity>{

    @Override public boolean matchesSafely(Entity e){
       // and here I do a bunch of asserts...
       assertNotNull(e.id);
       // etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
       description.appendText("is valid entity");
    }

    @Factory
    public static <T> Matcher<Entity> validEntity() {
        return new IsValidEntity();
    } 
}
```

OK, fine, I can then do

```
assertThat(entity, is(validEntity());
```

in a JUnit test, peachy.

But I can't do

```
assertThat(entity, not(validEntity());
```

because the `validEntity` fails with broken asserts, while for not I guess it should just `return false`.

Clearly I'm doing something backwards here but I'm not sure what's the most clever way of doing these custom matchers. Or maybe I shouldn't be using `TypeSafeMatcher` at all but doing something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `matchesSafely` method should be rewritten to avoid throwing assertion failures. Instead, just perform the checks manually and then return `false` if necessary.

Then, you can negate it in the manner you desire without consequence.

Comment: Yes, obviously I can do that, but then I can't use other clever assert methods to do the checking I want to do. 

Maybe I should be doing something completely different to group together a bunch of asserts?

Comment: @PapaFreud If you absolutely must use assertions to perform your checks, then you can wrap them in a try/catch and return `false` from your catch clause.

Comment: This is what I did, catching an AssertionError and returning false. 

But what... if I "absolutely must" use assertions? Well, no, not as such, but... I AM writing unit tests using hamcrest matchers. Using assertions does not strike me as a particularly queer thing to do in these circumstances. Is it?

Comment: @PapaFreud Yes, in this case it is. You are implementing a method whose task is to return a boolean value, not throw assertion exceptions. It doesn't really matter if you want to achieve this with assertions in a try/catch or not, provided you return `true` for OK and `false` for not, then all is well.

Comment: OK. Point taken. But I'm only doing this because I wanted to group asserts together in the first place. As I said - maybe I should be doing something different?

Comment: @PapaFreud I would just write a static method `assertIsValid(Obj o)` somewhere that performs all your asserts on the object argument.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just did. I just somehow thought I should be doing something fancier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `assert` methods in the `matchesSafely`. You should only be doing boolean logic to return either true or false. It is the responsibility of the calling code to throw the assert error and / or wrap in the not. Therefore you should be doing something like this:

```
public boolean matchesSafely(...){
       boolean result = true;
       result &= value1 == value2;
       result &= entity.getVal2() == someOtherVal2;
       return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are more correct, another approach might be to catch your exceptions within the matcher and then return false while swallowing the exception and returning true otherwise.

This is not ideal.